# MySQL Check if a value is within the range of values derived from a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I need help with a query, I have a table ,here is an example

```
Item Code   Qty   Price   Supplier
1234          1      20    A
1234          3      15    B
1234          6      2     C
4321          2      8     D
4321          7      1     A
4321          9      5     G
5432          8      10    E
5432          3      2     F
5467          5      9     H
5467          5      7     K
```

I have a subquery which contains distinct Item code, max(price) and 75%of max(price),this is the result.

```
Item Code   Max value   Min Value
1234         20          15
4321         8           6
5432        10           7.5
5467         9           6.75
```

and I need pull only those rows from first table if the price falls within the range of second table for the particular Item Code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us more about your second table.

Comment: Edit your question and show the queries you already have. Also, show the schema of the 2nd table.

Comment: The 2nd table is the subquery that has the distinct item code and max price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get first the max price per itemCode and join to the main table using itemCode and chwck that the price is between 75% of max and max price per item.

```
Select tbl.*
From myTable tbl
Join (
Select item_code,
         max(price) as mx,
         Round(max(price)*.75,0) as mx75
From myTable
Group by item_code) tab
On tbl.item_code = tab.item_code
And tbl.price between tab.mx75 and tab.mx
Order by 1, 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You might give this a try:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM items a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        item_code,
        MAX(Price) as Max_Value,
        MAX(Price) * 0.75 as Min_Value
    FROM items
    GROUP BY item_code) b
ON a.item_code = b.item_code
WHERE a.price between b.Min_Value AND b.Max_Value
order by a.item_code, a.price ASC
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: @SQLSurfer: If this works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: @SloanThrasher the result just gives me the first Item Code 1234  ,            Item_Code Qty Price Supplier
1234 1 20.00 A
1234 3 15.00 B

Comment: It doesn't take the other item codes that satisfies the given condition